# Targetting button outside of a form in action.php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I currently have 2 forms, which adds data to my database. They both work, but they each have their own submit button - and I only want one submit button to collect the data from all the forms.

I found some javascript that should set the deal;

```
$("#submitbutton").click(function(){
$("#form1").submit();
$("#form2").submit();
});
```

The button I'm targetting is outside of both forms and looks like this:

```
<input id="submitbutton" type="button" value="add">
```

I'm pretty sure the reason why it doesn't work, is because of the way my php is written. I'm targetting the submit button in each form to excecute the php. 
You can see the forms and php below.

One of the forms allows you to upload a picture;

```
<form id="form1" action="addimage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="image" />
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="sumit" value="Upload" />
        </form>
```

The action file contains this php;

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['sumit']))
    {
      if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])== FALSE)
      {
        echo "Please select an image.";
      }
      else
      {
        $image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $image= file_get_contents($image);
        $image= base64_encode($image);
        saveimage($name,$image);
      }
    }
        displayimage();
        function saveimage($name,$image)
        { 
      $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
      mysql_select_db("ssdb",$con);
      $qry="insert into pictures (name,image) values ('$name','$image')";
      $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
      if($result)
      {
                //echo "<br/>Image uploaded.";
            }
            else
            {
                //echo "<br/>Image not uploaded.";
            }
    }
            function displayimage()
            {
      $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
      mysql_select_db("ssdb",$con);
      $qry="select * from pictures";
      $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'.$row[2].' "> ';
      }
      mysql_close($con); 
    }
  ?>
```

The other form lets you choose between multiple categories collected from my database;

```
<form id="form2" action="checkbox.php" method="post">
          <label for="Category">Category</label>
          <br />
            <!-- iterate through the WHILE LOOP  -->
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_category)): ?>
              <!-- Echo out values {id} and {name}   -->
              <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value=" <?php echo $row['id']; ?> "><?php echo $row['name'] . '<br />'; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
           <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default"/>
         </form>
```

And has the following php;

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$checkbox = $_POST['category'];
if($_POST["Submit"]=="Submit")
{
  for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkbox);$i++) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO placecategory (category_id) VALUES ('".$checkbox[$i]."')";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  }
  echo "Category is inserted";
}
?>
```

I've tried targetting the new button I made that should excecute the javascript, but it doesn't seem to work because that button is out of the form.

Is there a way to target the button outside of the form so the php excecutes when that is clicked? Or how can I rewrite this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Like @Placeholder I don't understand what you're trying to get. Do you want: 1) to have 3 buttons (1 for each form and 1 more outside)? Seems totally inconsistent. 2) 2 form buttons, each commanding submission of both forms? 3) Only 1 external button for the same? Please add precisions.

Comment: I only want 1 external button that is outside all the forms. When that is pressed all the forms are submitted. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: Does clicking the external button load a new page? Or does it call some JavaScript?

Comment: Generally, if you click on a submit button to load a new page without JavaScript, the contents of the form of that button is placed in the PHP $_POST object. Every other form is ignored. `$("#form1").submit();` should reload the page, preventing the following line from being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand completely what you're trying to do but try this with HTML5 add `form="form1"` and `form="form2"` for your second one and let me know if this works.

```
<form id="form1" action="addimage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image" />
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="sumit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<input type="submit" name="sumit" value="Upload" form="form1" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It doesn't work if I put the submit button outside of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Taking in account your complementary comment, then your proposed javascript sequence would work, assumed you have:

- suppressed buttons such as `<input type="submit"... />` from both forms
- added the new button `<button name="submitbutton">...</button>` outside of the forms
- modified the PHP parts accordingly, referencing `$_POST['submitbutton']` instead of `sumit` and `Submit` respectively

You didn't report **how** it currently don't work, so the above steps target only the changes precisely related to the fact you replace two in-form buttons by a unique out-form one.

But something may turn wrong elsewhere. I notably noticed the non-usual way (at least for me) you get and process the image. Also you must ensure that your javascript part have really been executed.

Let me know if it doesn't work yet, than adding precise description of what turns wrong.

---

**Edit, based on your provided comments and live preview.**

Fully testing is not really possible because the server PHP part is out of reach, bue we can use Firebug to debug JS part.

So adding a breakpoint we can observe that, as soon as `$("#form1").submit();` has been executed, the server returns a new page with the "Place has been added!" message.
In the other hand, without any breakpoint set, the server returns returns a new page with the "Categorie inserted!" message.

Though the OP didn't show the `addingplace.php` part of the current live preview, and comparing with the `checkbox.php` part, we can guess that:

1. In the reduced execution part, the first step `addingplace.php` did work as expected.
2. What we observe while whole execution merely means that all three parts have worked as expected, but each one having its returned message overwritten by the next one, but for the last one.

In other terms, when you comment "it only seems to submit the last form", this is a false impression based on what you only can see.
To ensure this is true or not **you should control what is really updated or not in your database.**
Let me know.

That said, it must be noted that this illustrates how the couple server-browser works in those circumstances: as already pointed by @David in a comment under the OP, to submit a form causes the browser to immediately receive a new page which overwrites the current one.

In the current example, it works because there are only few forms, and all three are submitted in a very reduced time, almost instantly: so the 3rd `submit()` can get executed before the 1st one's returned page comes.

So the recommended way to achieve the whole work in your example is merely to use only one form, with its unique submit button. BTW I wonder why you wanted to have this more complicated structure with three forms: what is the expected benefit?

Last point, outside of the precise issue you reported: you should pay attention to how you're coding. There is a lot of inconstencies in the HTML part, e.g.: a `<html><body>` part inside the already existing `<body>`; an exotic `<br></br>`; also you kept a supplemental button in the 1st form.

Comment: Thanks for your response cFreed, as for now the problem seems to be when I click the submit button, which is placed outside all of the forms, it only seems to submit the last form in my javascript.


I got a live preview of the form here; http://stephanolsen.dk/formtest

Comment: So if $("#form1").submit(); is last in the script, that is the one getting submitted.